# COUNT, Minimum Value per course without subquery

Tags: mysql

Can anyone help me find the minimum student action per course? Listed like this:

```
+-------------+--------------------------+  
| Course      | Lowest Action            |  
+-------------+--------------------------+ 
| Maths Y1    |                          |  
| English C   |                          |   
| Science Y1  |                          |
```

for all users, even if they are not in the log table, without a subquery? My thanks to @luckylwk for assistance with my initial query. I have a solution with a subquery but want to put this into a variable for a much large query.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(tbl_log.action)
    lastname,
    c.fullname,
FROM tbl_log
JOIN tbl_user ON tbl_log.userid = tbl_user.id
JOIN tbl_course ON tbl_log.course = tbl_course.id
GROUP BY tbl_log.userid, tbl_log.course

LOG TABLE     

+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+  
| Field       | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |  
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+  
| id          |                     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |  
| time        |                     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |  
| userid      |                     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |  
| course      |                     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |  
| action      |                     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |  
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+  

USER Table

+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+  
| Field        | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |  
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+  
| id           |                     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |  
| username     |                     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |  
| userpassword |                     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |  
| lastname     |                     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |  
| firstname    |                     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |  
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+  

COURSE table

+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+  
| Field        | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |  
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+  
| id           |                     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |  
| category     |                     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |  
| fullname     |                     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |  
| shortname    |                     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |   
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I link the users together via the enrolment and context tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT 
 tbl_course.course_name,
 MIN(tbl_log.action) as Lowest_Action
 FROM tbl_log
 JOIN tbl_user ON tbl_log.userid = tbl_user.id
 JOIN tbl_course ON tbl_log.course = tbl_course.id
 GROUP BY tbl_course.course_name
```

See <kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/57e8f/1)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks @Edper, unfortunately, this does not work for me because each record in the log is 1 action. For example, user1 on course 4 1 action, user2 on course 4 1 action. I need to count all of the user actions on each course, then find the minimum of all the user actions. So if I have 20 users, I need to work out the minimum actions performed by a user of the 20 users. Thanks for giving it a go though. You solution would have worked if I didn't need to COUNT the rows.